# WDS ImageUnattend does not run

Tags: windows, service, deployment

We've successfully set-up WDS (Windows Deployment Services) and had it all working (it's serving an unattended Windows 7 x64 installation, the user only has to F12 then wait for the install to finish) but it no longer works the way it did before.

We're trying to F12 the exact same machine where it used to work. The WDS part of the installation is still automatic (unattended) but ImageUnattend.xml does not seem to run on the client at all now, it gets stuck at the language selection (everything after that is manual as well which is supposed to be automatic).

Inspecting C:\windows\panther on the client machine shows that WDS pops up with an error: *WDS CallBack_WdsClient_CopyPrivatesDone: Failed to process client unattend variables.*

Changing "%MACHINENAME%" to "*" in the ImageUnattend.xml file makes it all automatic again, however it then renames the computer incorrectly.

The variable %MACHINENAME% worked before, so why does it not work now? Has anyone else met this issue before?

Using a different user (domain administrator) in the ImageUnattend.xml file does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Yes, a minimal error in `unattend.xml`, and you're screwed and put off with a (seemingly) unrelated error message. I also got the "... Failed to process client unattend _variables_." which turned out to be caused by comments (valid XML syntax) in unattend.xml, which had worked before but failed with an 20H2/19041 install image.
It seems there is someone at Microsoft who [does not like valid XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/start-layout-xml-desktop#supported-elements-and-attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless of attempts with at least 15 new ImageUnattend.xml files, I decided to restart the server and use the original files I knew worked before.

This fixed it.